# Verilog: Can two always blocks be merged into one always block?

Tags: verilog

I have a Question that two `always @(posedge clk) blocks` would be identical to one `always @(posedge clk) block`.

For example,

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    // do task1
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
   // do task2
end
```

is identical to this one?

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    // do task1
    // do task2
end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

No, they are not.

In the first example the two tasks are executed in parallel. In the second they are executed sequentially.

Here is an extreme example where things not only are different but there is even a nasty side effect. So let's first define a clock and two tasks:

```
reg clk,a,b;

   initial
   begin
      clk = 1'b0;
      a = 1'b0;
      b = 1'b0;
      forever
         #50 clk = ~clk;
   end

task task1;
begin
   #10;
   a <= 1'b1;      
   #30;
   a <= 1'b0;
end
endtask


task task2;
begin
   #10;
   b <= 1'b1;      
   #70;
   b <= 1'b0;
end
endtask
```

Now if we call the tasks separately each finishes before the end of the clock cycle.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    task1;
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
   task2;
end
```

This gives the following waveform in which the pattern repeats every clock cycle and the two waveform are in parallel:

[image]

I we use the second code, the total time in the task is *longer then the clock cycle*.

```
always @(posedge clk) 
begin
   task1;
   task2;
end
```

This gives a **different** waveform in which the patterns are sequentially, but also repeats every **second** clock cycle.

[image]

Comment: **Nice counter example!!** but, WHAT IF there's no delay code(ex: #10, #30)? for example, just doing, "a <= 1;", "b<=1;" for each "always @(posedge clk)" block. In this case, is it possible to merge them?

Comment: You still have the problem of serial versus parallel execution which can lead to differences if there are dependencies. In **most** Verilog cases it does not matter but you asked a general question.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. If there are no dependancies between the two tasks, which normally there won't be for synthesizable RTL, then it does not matter.

But if there is a requirement that task1 executes before task2, then only the single `always` block can guarantee that.